# I need to initialize a dictionary using the value from a variable/list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary, iteration

I have a list of iteratable values ["A","B","C"...more than 1000].
I need to make a dictionary for all the elements of the list based on a datafile, in the following way:

```
A={} 
B={}
C={}
..
```

I need a way to initialize the elements as a dictionary. How can I do this?

Example:
list1=["abc","def","ghi"] is converted to

```
abc={} 
def={} 
ghi={}
```

Comment: I have more than 6.5 million rows of data in a csv file, which fall within 1000 known categories. I need to create a dictionary for all of the known categories, and later store the key and value based on my csv file.

Comment: You definitely don't need to create a bunch of variables. Just use a dictionary, e.g. `data = {k: {} for k in list1}`

Comment: Thanks @juanpa.arrivillaga. I'll test that out

Comment: Even if you managed to create 1000 variables, how would you write any logical code using them?

Answer (score 0):

As it has been recommended in the comments you can have one single dictionary instead of a bunch of variables. You can do so using a dictionary comprehension.

```py
list1=["abc","def","ghi"]
list1_as_a_dict = {elem: {} for elem in list1}
```